# Java: Using scanner to read in boolean values failing.

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cardhelp2{

private static String[] pairArray={"A,A","K,K","Q,Q","J,J","10,10","9,9","8,8","7,7","6,6","5,5","4,4","3,3","2,2"};

public static void generateRandom(int k){
 int minimum = 0;
 int maximum = 13;
 for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
   {
     int randomNum = minimum + (int)(Math.random()* maximum);
     System.out.print("Player " + i +" , You have been dealt a pair of: ");
     System.out.println(pairArray[randomNum]);
   }
} //reads array and randomizes cards

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("How many players would you like to play with? ");
 int m = scan.nextInt();
 generateRandom(m);

//displays the cards

___________________________________________________
System.out.println("Would you like to play?");
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")||scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
System.out.println("This will be fun");
} else if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("n")||scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
System.out.println("Maybe next time");
} else { 
System.out.println("Invalid character");

 }
 }
}
```

Im having trouble understanding why the end part is not working, I've been told i need to change scanner.next(); to a variable but im not sure how to do it and get the code working. Is there a simple way of reading in the users answer then displaying a response to the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your conditional expression

```
if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")||scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
```

calls `scanner.next()` twice, which means the second call will read/wait for more input. Instead you need to call it only once, store the result and use that in the comparison:

```
String tmp = scanner.next();
if(tmp.equalsIgnoreCase("y")||tmp.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Would you like to play?");`

 `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

   `if(tmp.equalsIgnoreCase("y")||tmp.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {`
 `System.out.println("This will be fun");`
  `} else (tmp.equalsIgnoreCase("n")||tmp.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {`
    `System.out.println("Maybe next time");`
   `}`
`}`
`}`

I have this but it doesnt seem to be correct

Comment: That seems to be correct.  Of course you can always try it :)

Comment: It says that the if statement is not a statement in the error message, it wont compile.

Comment: You left out `String tmp = scanner.next();` and change `else(` to `else if(` (see [here](http://ideone.com/avtKm))

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the user inputs "yes".

At

```
if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")||scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
```

`Scanner.next()` produces "yes" in the first test.  So the code is effectively

```
"yes".equalsIgnoreCase("y")
```

Which is false, so it moves to the next test:

```
scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")
```

Here's where your issue is.

the "yes" entered has already been consumed by the first test.  Now the Scanner has nothing in the buffer.

If you want to test the SAME input again, you must capture it, and use that in your tests.

So

```
String userReply= Scanner.next();
if(userReply.equalsIgnoreCase("y")||userReply.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {...
```

This is becauswe, with each call to `scanner.next()`, the `Scanner` returns the next value in the stream, and then *MOVES PAST IT*

If the user had entered "yes" and then "no", the tests would be performed like this:

```
if("yes".equalsIgnoreCase("y")||"no".equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change the way of `Scanner`'s calls.

The user input `\n` and `Scanner` seems don't follow with the next token. Then you need read line by line.
:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many players would you like to play with? ");
    int m = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()); // May thrown NumberFormatException
    generateRandom(m);

    //displays the cards

    System.out.print("Would you like to play? ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("This will be fun");
    } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println("Maybe next time");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid character");
    }
 }
```